# efi partition Issue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

**How to restore my GRUB so that my laptop boots properly?**

**Update 1:** Is there a possibility that there are 2 grubs installed, Is that the reason the **outputs from *ls* commands are different** (outputs are shown below)?

**Laptop Model: asus rog gl503ge**

Recently I had used the boot-repair tool to repair my GRUB when I got the GRUB terminal error. Unfortunately, there was an error in doing so. When I used the boot-repair tool, the windows EFI partition was selected by default in its advanced options. So the error changed the boot/ folder in my ubuntu (I have attached the contents of the folder down here). This is causing the booting issue i.e, whenever I tried to boot my laptop I get the GRUB terminal. So, if I use the boot-repair tool once more, I am temporarily able to access the ubuntu machine for one time i.e, if I reboot my laptop more than once, I once again get stuck with the GRUB terminal.

**Contents in boot/ folder:**

```
akshith@akshith-rog:/boot$ ls
config-5.8.0-45-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-5.8.0-48-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-5.8.0-49-generic      System.map-5.8.0-45-generic
config-5.8.0-50-generic      System.map-5.8.0-48-generic
efi                          System.map-5.8.0-49-generic
grub                         System.map-5.8.0-50-generic
initrd.img                   vmlinuz
initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic
initrd.img-5.8.0-48-generic  vmlinuz-5.8.0-48-generic
initrd.img-5.8.0-49-generic  vmlinuz-5.8.0-49-generic
initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic  vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
initrd.img.old               vmlinuz.old
memtest86+.bin

akshith@akshith-rog:/boot$ cd efi/EFI/

akshith@akshith-rog:/boot/efi/EFI$ ls
Boot  Microsoft  ubuntu

akshith@akshith-rog:/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu$ ls
BOOTX64.CSV  fw  fwupx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi

akshith@akshith-rog:/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/$ ls 
bkpbootx64.efi  bootx64.efi  fbx64.efi  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi
```

**GRUB terminal output:**

```
grub> ls (hd0,1)
Partition hd0, 1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'SYSTEM', UUID 2082-8A95- Partition start at 1024K1B - Total size 266240K1B

grub> ls (hd0, 1)/
efi/ System Volume Information/

grub> ls (hdo, 1)/efi
Microsoft/ Boot/ ubuntu/

grub> ls (hdo, 1)/efi/ubuntu/
fw/ fuupx64.efi grubx64.efi grub.cfg shimx64.efi mmx64.efi bootx64.csv

grub> ls (hdo, 1)/efi/Boot/
fbx64.efi mmx64.efi bkpbootx64.efi bootx64.efi grubx64.efi
```

Boot-repair tool :

[image]

**Update 1:** As I told above I am able to boot into ubuntu temporarily so, when GRUB menu appeared I pressed 'esc' and went into GRUB terminal and checked what all contents are there and found this:

```
grub> ls 
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) 

grub> ls (hd1,1)
    Partition hd1,1: Filesystem type fat- Label `SYSTEM', UUID 20B2-BA95 Partition start at 1024KIB Total size 266240KB

grub> ls (hd1,1)/
efi/ System Volume Information/

grub> ls (hd1,1)/efi/
Microsoft/ Boot/ ubuntu/

grub> ls (hd1,1)/efi/ubuntu/
fw/ fuupx64.efi grubx64.efi grub.cfg shimx64.efi mmx64.efi bootx64.csv

grub> ls (hd1,1)/efi/Boot/
fbx64.efi mmx64.efi bkpbootx64.efi bootx64.efi grubx64.efi

grub> ls (hd1,1)/efi/Microsoft/
Boot/ Recovery/

grub> ls (hd0,1)/
$AttrDef $Badclus $Bitmap $Boot $Extend/ $LogFile $HFT $HFTMirr SRECYCLE.BIN/ $Secure $UpCase $Volume ........Contents of my D Drive in Windows
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. All ext needs to be included in the question so everyone can read it.

Comment: Please check this now. Thankyou.

Comment: Can you select the ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu, same key you used to boot USB installer? What brand/model system? Some require you to go into UEFI and change boot order in UEFI. Otherwise, post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair as it suggests.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bqPNCfTjrS/  This was the summary report for the recent try. My model is asus rog gl503ge.  Sorry, but what is the key you are talking about?

Comment: Since you are temporarily able to access Ubuntu, the straightward solution is to reinstall grub2 with `grub-install` while making sure the ESP where grubx64.efi locates is to be correctly mounted via */etc/fstab*.

Comment: @funicorn can u please elaborate.

Comment: @Akshith First boot ubuntu as you did before, then run `grub-install` to reinstall grub onto the system. The default installation would write grub image to */boot/grub* and write efi-boot files to */boot/efi/*. After manual booting, check if your efi system partition (ESP) has been mounted to `/boot/efi` correctly. If so, you can run `sudo grub-install` directly. If not, you have to add `--efi-directory=/path/to/ESP_mount_point`. In addition, you'd better check */etc/fstab* if the ESP is designated to mount at `/boot/efi` as normal.

Comment: @funicorn a small doubt, as said above in the question there is a folder for microsoft in /boot/efi/EFI so, when I do as u said will it be affected? One more doubt, is the folder named microsoft necessary for booting into windows?

Comment: @funicorn please check the update, Thankyou.

Comment: @Akshith The microsoft folder won't be affected. And yes it's necessary for starting windows boot manager. The `ls` outputs are confusing, because the UUID's of (hd0,1) and (hd1,1) are different. If we omit this inconsistence, the outputs can be understood in that a grub located in a certain disk was started which assigns certain disk number.

Comment: @funicorn as u said I have tried to run ```sudo grub-install``` and checked the mount point and it is as expected. Still after running this command issue is not resolved :(

Comment: @Akshith Sorry it didn't help. If sticking to the solution, I suggest adding more disk/partition specifics by `parted -l` and `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`.

Comment: No need of sorries bro :)
I need to say it as I didn't reply but i will try :).

Comment: @funicorn Sorry for the late reply but I am stuck with another issue i.e, Now, the boot menu is appearing I don't know how but, it appeared after my recent windows update and I am facing the grub terminal issue, If I run ```sudo apt upgrade``` in ubuntu. What do you think has happened?